# Paypal pro Payment using Stored Credt Card Details

Tags: php, paypal

We are storing the credit card details on paypal server.

And the response is like this

stdClass Object ( [id] => CARD-14C32505AV6044027KQ537UQ [state] => ok [payer_id] => GI6WdoVY6zOq1413201872 [type] => visa [number] => xxxxxxxxxxxx1111 [expire_month] => 11 [expire_year] => 2018 [first_name] => Anu [last_name] => Jose [valid_until] => 2017-10-12T00:00:00Z [create_time] => 2014-10-13T12:04:34Z [update_time] => 2014-10-13T12:04:34Z [links] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-14C32505AV6044027KQ537UQ [rel] => self [method] => GET ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-14C32505AV6044027KQ537UQ [rel] => delete [method] => DELETE ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-14C32505AV6044027KQ537UQ [rel] => patch [method] => PATCH ) ) )

Is it possible to do a transaction using this credit card ID?
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely you can do the payments using those stored card by using the credit card id received above .

I have included the curl request that you can use :

**Request**

```
curl -v POST  "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer A0430YIJHh.TrJ7DuXoVVSzzRD9BiNhc7.JUdtWFV9bm6PM" -d "{\"intent\":\"sale\",\"payer\":{\"payment_method\":\"credit_card\",\"funding_instruments\":[{\"credit_card_token\":{\"credit_card_id\":\"CARD-7F19874*H7676925VKQ55ALQ\"}}]},\"transactions\":[{\"amount\":{\"total\":\"7.47\",\"currency\":\"USD\"},\"description\":\"This is the payment transaction description.\"}]}"
```

**Response**

```
{"id":"PAY-17C52753U3213490GKQ56FJQ","create_time":"2014-10-13T14:33:10Z","updat
e_time":"2014-10-13T14:33:28Z","state":"approved","intent":"sale","payer":{"paym
ent_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card_token":{"credit_c
ard_id":"CARD-7F116246H7676925VKQ55ALQ","last4":"0331","type":"visa","expire_mon
th":"11","expire_year":"2018"}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"7.47","cur
rency":"USD","details":{"subtotal":"7.47"}},"description":"This is the payment t
ransaction description.","related_resources":[{"sale":{"id":"0TD97130MF446714A",
"create_time":"2014-10-13T14:33:10Z","update_time":"2014-10-13T14:33:28Z","amoun
t":{"total":"7.47","currency":"USD"},"state":"completed","parent_payment":"PAY-1
7C52753U3213490GKQ56FJQ","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/pay
ments/sale/0TD97130MF446714A","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.
sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/0TD97130MF446714A/refund","rel":"refund","me
thod":"POST"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-17
C52753U3213490GKQ56FJQ","rel":"parent_payment","method":"GET"}]}}]}],"links":[{"
href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-17C52753U3213490GK
Q56FJQ","rel":"self","method":"GET"}]}
```

Request in JSON format  :

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card_token": {
          "credit_card_id": "CARD-7F19874*H7676925VKQ55ALQ"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
```

Response :

```
{
  "id": "PAY-8U155502YW812893MKQ55D7Q",
  "create_time": "2014-10-13T13:22:06Z",
  "update_time": "2014-10-13T13:22:27Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card_token": {
          "credit_card_id": "CARD-7F19874*H7676925VKQ55ALQ",
          "last4": "0331",
          "type": "visa",
          "expire_month": "11",
          "expire_year": "2018"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "7.47"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "5U920323FW4849716",
            "create_time": "2014-10-13T13:22:06Z",
            "update_time": "2014-10-13T13:22:27Z",
            "amount": {
              "total": "7.47",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "state": "completed",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-8U155502YW812893MKQ55D7Q",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5U920323FW4849716",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5U920323FW4849716/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8U155502YW812893MKQ55D7Q",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8U155502YW812893MKQ55D7Q",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use the below php code :

```
<?php

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

$client="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$secret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json->access_token);
}

// Now doing txn after getting the token 

$ch = curl_init();

$data = '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card_token": {
          "credit_card_id": "CARD-76K83451273207050KQ6MXDQ"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer ".$json->access_token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);


if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json);
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi can u pls give more details about the second request method

Comment: Got this response when i tried {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"3ddab4e897912"}

Comment: The same code is working for me. Did you put your credentials and the credit card id in the code?

Comment: can u plz try with these credentials  $client="AXclRxADU6bhIhd2jF13L56hf3i23Csauat6fvBdAgntuefbNWQU1p5jbiiL";
$secret="EKOarRDlB7hJBXUXUXlz4r-zFnIJT6G-EOMM2jz24qWr81OJbfZ-iKjXVHuI";

Comment: It seems like you have stored the test credit card number "4111111111111111" . Can you try to store this credit card number first "4860444400352960" with any expiration date and cvv2=012 and then use the new card id for payment?

Comment: thank you so much.It is working for me.And one more doubt . Can we perform payment to more than one paypal account using the "parent_payment" in the response.It means if i hav payed a 100 USD ;by using the parent_payment" in the response,is it possible to transfer 50 USD to a@gmail.com and 50 uSD to b@mail.com(assume both are paypal email ids)

Comment: Currently REST API doesn't support the parallel payments . So , you can't do achieve this at this moment.

Comment: can u please explain ;in which account this amount will get credited;

Comment: It should be the account to which the client id and secret belongs to .

Comment: Hello Eshan! I want to delete CC detail from vault, what need to pass in curl.

Comment: You just need to pass the credit card id that was returned when you created when the card was stored in the vault . You can refer the belwo url for more info :https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#delete-a-stored-credit-card